# Can we make use of local variables inside Postgresql insert statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a simple insert query for inserting records into the database with local variables.
Example : Simple insert query looks like:

```
Insert Into TableName(id, firstName, lastName)
Values ('123','ABC','XYZ')
```

Now I want to use some local variable for assigning the values inside the Insert statement, something like this:

```
variable_Name UserFirstName = 'ABC'
variable_Name UserLastName = 'XYZ'
variable_Name UserId = '123'

Insert Into TableName(id, firstName, lastName)
Values (@UserId,@UserFirstName,@UserLastName)
```

How this can be done?

Comment: Do you want to use the variables in SQL or in C# or LinQ?

Comment: I want to use them in the postgresql query and not in c#